# Can Kibana4 show raw record info for thing in the chart?

Tags: elasticsearch, charts, kibana

I create a vertical bar chart whose `metrics` is `Y-Axis` about Max `response_time`, and `buckets` is `X-Axis` about `@timestamp`.

How can I find the corresponding raw record for one vertical bar? Or can I show other relative info about that bar record in the chart at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show raw record after clicking on a specific timestamp bar, you can do it in following way:-

Click on the timestamp bar on X-Axis. Just below your searchbar the filter will be applied showing in an oval shape. Now you can pin the filter in 2 ways:-

1.By clicking on Actions beside the applied filter & selecting Pin.

OR

2. Hovering over the filter and selecting 2nd option from the left.

Then go to Discover Page from the same window wherein you will see raw data matching to the filter applied.

Comment: I tried but it seems that the timestamp bar in X-Axis is not clickable and nothing show up in the filter part. I'm using Kibana 4.

Comment: Can you confirm whether data is populated in Discover Page of Kibana?
Also a sample record of your raw data will be helpful.

Comment: Just after I wrote down the sample record, I found out that I misunderstood your solution... Your answer works! Thanks!